# Close date + 1 business day with workflow

Tags: workflow, case

I am trying to modify this code (found on forums) to update the Expected_Ship_Date__c to CloseDate + one business day
Im not getting any errors but, the field is not updating

Monday + 1
Tuesday  + 1
Wednesday  + 1
Thursday  + 1
Friday + 3
Saturday + 2
Sunday  + 1

```
CASE(MOD( CloseDate - DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 ), 
1, CloseDate + 1, 
2, CloseDate + 1, 
3, CloseDate + 1, 
4, CloseDate + 1, 
5, CloseDate + 3, 
6, CloseDate + 2, 
CloseDate + 1 
)
```

Comment: That strategy also does not account for holidays. If you want to add one business day, `Apex` makes more sense.

Comment: Your formula could have been written as: `CloseDate + CASE(MOD(CloseDate-Date(1900, 1, 7), 7), 5, 3, 6, 2, 1)` That said, it looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula should work. Make sure you verify the following:

## Is your evaluation criteria correct?

In this case, you might want to simply set it to "Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited".

## Is your rule criteria correct?

For something that should keep in sync, consider using "Run this rule if the following formula evaluates to true", and use the formula "TRUE". This means the rule will always execute. Or, you could use criteria such as "IsWon" so the date only updates upon closing the opportunity.

## Is your workflow rule active?

Make sure you've clicked on the "activate" button after creating your rule, or it won't fire.

## Other Notes

There's a limit to how much "formula" you can have, so I'd suggest using the following:

```
CloseDate + CASE(MOD(CloseDate-Date(1900, 1, 7), 7), 5, 3, 6, 2, 1)
```

Assuming everything above is correct, the calculation should work correctly.

Comment: @fox. Thanks for your response. Still not updating. Evaluation criteria is as you said.  Criteria is criteria are met Opportunity: Won equals TRUE . Field to Update = Opportunity: Expected ship date Specify new field value  = Use formula to set the new value . Formula is  verbatim..    CloseDate + CASE(MOD(CloseDate-Date(1900, 1, 7), 7), 5, 3, 6, 2, 1)

Comment: I had expected this to fire every time I edited an opportunity where Opportunity Won = True. I ended up changing the criteria to Opportunity Stage = Closed Won. If I change the an existing Opportunity Stage Closed Won to something else, save it and change it again to Closed Won it works. @fox, your abbreviated code works flawlessly.